# SwiftUI get current rotation Value

Tags: swiftui

I would like to get the current rotation value in degrees from the roation3DEffect.

If the value passes -90 , I want to change the text.

How do I get the value?

This is my code so far:

```
@State var rotation = false

[…]

ZStack {
    Rectangle()
        .foregroundColor(.green)

    Text("1")
}
.frame(width: 120, height: 60)
.rotation3DEffect(Angle(degrees: rotation ? -180 : 0), axis: (x: 10, y: 0, z: 0), anchor: .bottom)

.animation(.linear(duration: 0.25))
.onTapGesture {
    self.rotation.toggle()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var degree = 0.0
    @State private var text = "1"

    var body: some View {

        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(.green)
                Text(text)

        }
        .frame(width: 120, height: 60)
        .rotation3DEffect(Angle(degrees: degree), axis: (x: 10, y: 0, z: 0), anchor: .bottom)

        .onTapGesture {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                self.text = ""
            }
            withAnimation(.linear(duration: 1)) {
                if self.degree == 0 {
                    self.degree += 180
                } else {
                    self.degree -= 180
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edited my code in response to your comment.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Im trying to hide the text change in the perspective. So the change should happened at 90°. Do you have any suggest for that particular behaviour?

Comment: See my updated code. The trick is to find the right time ( 50% of the whole animation time) and not the particular 90° value.